# tf.set_random_seed seems doesn't work, any better way to make tensorflow code reproducible?

Tags: tensorflow, random-seed

I want to reproduce my result, I used the following lines to fix the randomness
    import numpy as np
    np.random.seed(1)
    import tensorflow as tf
    tf.set_random_seed(1)

But I still get different results at each run. any idea how to fix?

Comment: Can you share a short example program where you are getting unreproducible results?

Answer (score 0):

You also have to set the seed of every operation that uses random numbers.

Tensorflow has two different seeds: the graph level seed and the operation level sedd.

For instance, [`tf.truncated_normal`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/truncated_normal) needs to have both the graph seed (that you set with `tf.set_random_seed(1)`) and the operation seed (the `seed` parameter) sat, in order to be reproducibile.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I am still confused, isn't the operation part of the graph? setting tf.set_random_seed(1) before initializing the graph is not enough?

Comment: Tensorflow has 2 different seeds, thus setting only one of them is not enough. You have to set both, the graph level seed and the op level seed, for every single operation that uses random numbers

Comment: I am confused as well, the doc of TF says "To make the random sequences generated by all ops be repeatable across sessions, set a graph-level seed". In other words you would need to set op-seed only if you didn't set graph-seed. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/framework/random_seed.py#L65